# HTTP client refuse connection on Grial Kit

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

I'm running the following code on Grial template but it's not working. On the other hand, it's working on an empty project. These are all the relevant data with the API running.

**//DATA SERVICE**

```
public class DataService
{

    private string Url = "http://mystroapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Company/validatecompany";

    public async Task<CompanyModel> ValidateCompany(CompanyModel model)
    {
        try
        {
           var httpClient = new HttpClient();
           var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

           StringContent content = new StringContent(json);
           content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("applicantion/json");

           var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(Url, content);
           var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           var company = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompanyModel>(result);

           return company;

        }  
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new CompanyModel();
        }
    }
}
```

**//MODEL**

```
public class CompanyModel
{

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyIdentification { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyApi { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

}
```

**//CALLING METHOD**

```
public Page GetMainPage()
{

    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CompanyIdentification))
    {
        CompanyModel companyModel = new CompanyModel();
        companyModel.CompanyIdentification = CompanyIdentification;

        var company = dt.ValidateCompany(companyModel);
        if (company.Id!=0)
        {
                CompanyApi = company.Result.CompanyApi;
                Settings.CompanyApi = CompanyApi;


                if (!IsLogin)
                    return new NavigationPage(new EmployeeLoginPage());
                else
                    return new RootPage();
            }

        }

       return new NavigationPage(new CompanyLoginPage());
    }
}
```

Please ask me to add more details if necessary.

I still can't figure out why it's not working on Grial UI template but working on other files.

Is there any references that I should have or any Android or iOS properties? I'm not so advanced in Xamarin.

Comment: You have to await `dt.ValidateCompany(companyModel)`.